# Can't get any Bump channel results

Tags: bump

I'm new to Blender and following Blender Guru's donut tutorials and I can't get any results with from the Bump node. I've gone through the steps of the tutorial twice and still nothing. What am I doing wrong?
[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to connect B&W textures (such as noise) to the _height_ input of the Bump Node, (not the _normal_). The _Normal_ socket is reserved for "proper" normal map image textures (the "purple-ish" ones).

Comment: Thank you Christopher!